# how to I write prisma query for date between condition?

Tags: prisma

how to I write prisma query for the following SQL, want to convert invoice_date_time which is date time column in mysql but 90% time I need this in dd-mm-yyyy format

```
select id, date_format(invoice_date_time,'%d-%m-%y') from invoices 
where date(invoice_date_time) between '2023-04-01' AND '2023-10-17' ;
```